# In PoA network, Signer node doesn't work and "Persisted the clean trie cache" log printed by Geth!

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I configured and launched a private network by Geth. Some nodes are signers, that should validate transactions and seal blocks. I expect signer nodes run syncedly ,do their job, validate transactions and seal block. Moreover, I expect we see sealing logs. But, they are not synced, they don't their job and we face to timed out error when a transaction sent by application. Geth logs on PowerShell are:

```
INFO [03-18|13:39:46.571] Writing clean trie cache to disk
INFO [03-18|13:39:46.576] Regenerated local transaction journal
INFO [03-18|13:39:46.581] Persisted the clean trie cache
```

Steps to the issue:

1. I initialized Geth:

   `geth --datadir C:\. . .\Local  --identity "PrivEth" init "C:\. . .\Local\Genesis.json"`
2. I run signers:

   `geth --datadir C:\. . .\Local --cache 256 --identity "PrivEth" --networkid 1111 --port 30300 --netrestrict 192.168.10.0/24  --nat extip:192.168.10.24 --ws --allow-insecure-unlock --ws.addr 192.168.10.24 --ws.port 8551 --ws.api eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner --ws.origins "*" --mine --miner.threads 10 --miner.etherbase <address>`
3. I run other nodes:

`geth --datadir C:\. . .\Local --cache 256 --identity "PrivEth" --networkid 1111 --port 30300 --netrestrict 192.168.10.0/24  --nat extip:192.168.10.24 --ws --allow-insecure-unlock --ws.addr 192.168.10.24 --ws.port 8551 --ws.api eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner --ws.origins "*"`

4. I peered all nodes by `admin.addPeer(<enode>)`.
5. These logs resulted by Geth:

   INFO [03-18|13:39:46.571] Writing clean trie cache to disk

   INFO [03-18|13:39:46.576] Regenerated local transaction journal

   INFO [03-18|13:39:46.581] Persisted the clean trie cache

System information:

Geth version: 1.11.4

OS: Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated new accounts and replaced them with the previous ones for each systems and I run nodes. This solved my problem but I don't know how this did it.